# python - regex replace everything between 2 strings only in the first occourence of a character

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
setAttr ".ftn" -type "string" "C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Project/sources/foobar.jpg";
```

And I want to replace `C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Project/sources` with the string `sources` and nothing else.

If I try a regex like `\"(.*)sources`

I get as group `.ftn" -type "string" "C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Project/`

I want to match only the first occourence before "sources", not the first from the start of the string. I can't predict what the path will be but the structure will be always the same (and the folder "sources" will always exists). A path could also be already `"sources/foobar.jpg";` and so it should not be considered. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Then use `"([^"]*)sources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
"(\S*?)sources
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/EFHLm6/2). `\S*?` will match characters different from whitespace and `*?` will match the shortest amount.

Another try:

```
.*"(.*?)sources
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/EFHLm6/3). The first `.*` will make the group capture the last match.